# Error while launching external scanner

Tags: eclipse

Error launching external sccanner info generator(gcc -E -P -v -dD C:/Documents/Workspace)

Do any one know what is the problem this is for the windows . I downloaded the exact C version without java support but still it is showing this error .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Might be a path problem.
Try copying the gcc.exe to c:\Windows as a test. It won't work from there stand-alone, but you should at least see some difference that will help you determine if your problem is indeed a PATH one.